# Use of Office 365 API (Rest API) with ASP Classic

Tags: asp.net, api, asp-classic, oauth-2.0, office365

Is it possible to use Office 365 API (Rest API) with ASP Classic?. I know we can use Office 365 API with ASP.Net. unfortunately i didn't Office 365 API with ASP Classic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Office 365 API (Rest API) with ASP Classic?

Technically, Office 365 API does not limit the platform and developing language.

But the libraries like **ADAL for .NET** will help  the developers authenticate the user with Azure AD and call the Office 365 API with token cache support on .NET platform. Missing the support of existing .NET libraries will require the developers to implement all of this from scratch.